# Crash in iOS 13 when using EAAccessoryManager -showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion

Tags: bluetooth, crash, ios13, eaaccessory

We are getting the following crashes on iOS 13 (only), when using the -showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFIlter:completion: method of EAAccessoryManager
In Crashlytics crash reports, the top of the stack trace shows this: [BluetoothDevice classicDevice]  doesNotRecognizeSelector:

This is a typical stack trace:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeb68a48 __exceptionPreprocess + 220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ae88ffa4 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1aea6c5a8 -[NSObject+ 193960 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 139
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeb6caf4 ___forwarding___ + 1323
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeb6ea7c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 91
5   BluetoothSettings               0x1d8836b00 -[BTAlert showAlertWithResult:] + 1047
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeac4288 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 19
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeac42d0 ___CFXRegistrationPost1_block_invoke + 63
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeac3630 _CFXRegistrationPost1 + 367
9   CoreFoundation                  0x1aeac32e8 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 103
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1aea3f59c -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1415
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeac2c38 _CFXNotificationPost + 1243
12  Foundation                      0x1aee1f138 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
13  Foundation                      0x1aef5122c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 231
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeae6a00 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
15  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeae6958 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 79
16  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeae60f0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 179
17  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeae123c __CFRunLoopRun + 1079
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1aeae0adc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 463
19  GraphicsServices                0x1b8a66328 GSEventRunModal + 103
20  UIKitCore                       0x1b2bdbae0 UIApplicationMain + 1935
21  Jolt                            0x100c7dc10 main + 2808848 (main.m:52)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x1ae96a360 start + 3
```

Comment: Got the same problem for iOS13 devices. Did you figure out a way to prevent it ?

Comment: No, we didn't.  Sorry.